# get_the_post_thumbnail ignores my default thumbnail size

Tags: post-thumbnails

My default thumbnail size is 150x150.  Therefore, if I use a custom thumbnail size, such as 75x75 it should use the thumbnail of 150x150 and shrink to fit to my size:

```
get_the_post_thumbnail( $item->ID, array(75,75))
```

However, it is basing the image off of a thumbnail size of 149x100.  The 150x150 image exists, but it refuses to use it.

I figured heck with that, I'll just create a custom 75x75 thumbnail and that will solve the problem:

```
functions.php
add_image_size( 'listp-thumb', 75, 75, true ); // thumbnails located in list posts
```

Now to call the new thumbnail:

```
get_the_post_thumbnail( $item->ID, 'listp-thumb')
```

The same thing happens. :(  Do I need to clear a custom query that may be interfering with this?

Comment: It turns out I didn't push the code changes to the live server yet.  So regenerating thumbnails did nothing. Whoops.

Its working now. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try installing [Ajax Rebuild Thumbnails](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ajax-thumbnail-rebuild/)

This will create the new image size.